# How can I prevent double checks in this function?

Tags: php

Here is a code to search and return the existing files from the given directories:

```
<?php
function getDirContents($directories, &$results = array()) {

    $length = count($directories);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

        if(is_file($directories[$i])) {
            if(file_exists($directories[$i])) {
                $path = $directories[$i];
                $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $results[] =  'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
            }

        } else {

            $files = array_diff(scandir($directories[$i]), array('..', '.'));
            foreach($files as $key => $value) {
                $path = $directories[$i].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
                if(is_dir($path)) {
                    getDirContents([$path], $results);
                } else {
                    $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                    $results[] =  'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
                }
            }

        }
        
    }

    return $results;
}

echo json_encode(getDirContents($_POST['directories']));
```

So you can pass an **array** of **file addresses** and **directories** and get what ever files inside those directories, Note if you pass a file address instead of a directory address the function checks if there is such a file and if there is it returns its address in the result .

The issue is for the directories it works fine **but** the files repeat twice in the result and  for each file the function double checks this if statement in the code:

```
if(is_file($directories[$i]))
```

Here is a result of the function note that `contemporary.mp3` and `Japanese.mp3`

has been re checked and added to the result.

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? That's so little code that you could even check for the problem using var_dump

Comment: There's no need to check `file_exists` after `is_file`. `is_file` will never be true if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Barmar That's the first one thanks...

Comment: I don't see any reason why files would be repeated, unless `$directories` contains both the filename and also its containing directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$directories` contains both a directory and a file within that directory, you'll add the file to the result for the filename and also when scanning the directory.

A simple fix is to check whether the filename is already in the result before adding it.

```
<?php
function getDirContents($directories, &$results = array()) {
    foreach ($directories as $name) {
        if(is_file($name)) {
            $path = $name;
            $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            $new_path = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
            if (!in_array($new_path, $results)) {
                $results[] =  $new_path;
            }
        } elseif (is_dir($name)) {
            $files = array_diff(scandir($name), array('..', '.'));
            foreach($files as $key => $value) {
                $path = $name.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
                if(is_dir($path)) {
                    getDirContents([$path], $results);
                } else {
                    $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                    $new_path = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
                    if (!in_array($new_path, $results)) {
                        $results[] =  $new_path;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```